# Android is there a easy way to back up your android project?

Tags: android

I keep messing up my android project.  I started save ing whole work space.  Is there a way to simply backup your peoject? For example iphon has a thing called snap shoot.
Is there something like this in eclips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also revert to a previous version if you are using Eclipse.
Eclipse has this nice functionality called **Local history** that allows it.
Right click on a file and use "*compare with...*" -> "*Local History*".

You can then compare your current version with old ones.
You can merge select part of the code or right click on the old version and replace all your current version with the old one.

Number of entries and duration of conservation of old version can be configured in Eclipse preferences in "*General*" -> "*Workspace*" -> "*Local history*"

Comment: Why, just what I was looking for, would have saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 5):

Ted,

Have you considered a [source code revision control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)??

There are a lot of options for this.  I personally use [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and a free hosting site [unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/).

Other user suggested options...

Revision control programs:

- [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)
- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)
- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)
- [CVS](http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/) (older)
- [tortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)
- [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)

Hosting Options:

- [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)
- [google code](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/) (must be open
  source)

Comment: This is by far better than snapshot. Gives you version control, ease of access from literally anywhere, plus at some point if you decide to share the source with another developer - that's a breeze too. Also to know how a revision control works is a must when you'll look for a job (I assume you haven't worked in a team before).

Comment: +1 for version control.  I would also throw out Git & github.com or Mercurial and bitbucket.org as other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

File -> Export... -> General -> Archive File

Or start using subversion (eclipse plugin: subclipse)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend downloading TortoiseSVN and using Subclipse. Look those up.

Comment: tortoise + jdeveloper = me duelen los pezones

Comment: Thank you for the help, yes I looked them up, seemed a little more complex then what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a backup of the project folder, rather than the entire workspace. Then if you need it again, create a new project from existing source using that folder later.

Comment: Thank you, thast does seem easer then copying the whole workspace