# Eclipse compare project with local history not available?

Tags: android, eclipse

I was looking for an easy way to backup an android project in eclipse and found this question: [Android is there a easy way to back up your android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274757/android-is-there-a-easy-way-to-back-up-your-android-project) the selected answer states that `"You can also revert to a previous version if you are using Eclipse. Eclipse has this nice functionality called Local history that allows it. Right click on a file and use "compare with..." -> "Local History"."`

However when I right click on the project and click compare with I only see the diabled option "Each other"

I checked `Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History` but everything seems ok.

Why isn't Eclipse backing up my project? What do I do to enable the option compare with local history?

---

EDIT I was clicking on the project folder and realised this function only works for individual files, what I am looking for is to restore the entire project. Is it possible to enable this on Eclipse?

Comment: If you want particular file to compare with your local history, you can right click on the editor where you generally write your code and then selecting compare with or replace with. Can't you?

Comment: I found the problem. I thought that worked with a whole project. (I was clicking on the project folder) That's what I want to do. Is it possible? I'm looking to backup/restore the whole project not individual files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it just does it file per file. Eclipse is not meant to be used as a version control mechanism. Notice that even though that's the "accepted" answer, it has only one upvote. The one with more upvotes is what you're looking for in this case. Just invest a little time to use a real Version control mechanism (like Git).

Also, Eclipse would not really "back up" anything, since everything would still be local and if your hard drive crashed, everything would be bye bye anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you against an SVN? I use [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) and it seems to work fine for backing up/creating new projects and updates/restoring to older versions if necessary. You can set up  a repository on a separate web server or on a local file server. You can get [local history](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm) but I don't believe this is very reliable. I would use regualar backups or set up an SVN. Once you get it set up and install the plug-ins, it works pretty well.